# Which would be a best way to organize the logic for Filters

Tags: c#, sql, filter

I want to refactor a **logic to filter the grid** of my application. I'd like to implement this logic only in the **Database**.

So, I have a grid which displays the data from more tables from DB. There are some `textBoxes` and `comboBoxes` where it sets the data for each filter it wants.

Now, it is a **HUGE Stored Procedure** in Database which works this way:

Initially selects **[ALL DATA]** from tables into a temporary table , 
after that,
according to fields that were filled with data (from application filter), it removes from **[ALL DATA]** that info which is **NOT LIKE SELECTED FILTER**

And so on foreach parameter which is set in the filter.

This way consumes much time, because initially selects all data, and then slowly removes those which don't need.

I don't want to create SQL queries on client side. I'd like to do that only to Database, or .... iimmmm, i don't know...

Which would be a best way, very optimized, which would run fast and return results in short time as possible?

I use C# and .NET 4.0 for client side, and MSSQL DB.

Thank you for advices.

Comment: I read about using ORM, SQL Cursors, .NET Reflection, make Dynamic SQL Queries according to selected filter options... which one would be the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend your stored procedure so that it only selects the required data into the temprorary table in the first place, rather than selecting everything and then deleting what isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

That's what ORMs are for. Don't build a dynamic SQL statement on the client side. Rather, build a LINQ query filter by filter. You'll get the benefits of being entirely dynamic, without the risk of SQL injection.

You can look at [this](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/linq-how-to-build-complex-queries-utilizing-deferred-execution-and-anonymous-types/) for an example.

Comment: OK, OK, I'll add a link to an example.

Comment: As ORM is an intermediary between client and server, it would make actions to run slowly than direct connection, or it is made in a way to work efficiently ?

Comment: Decently designed ORMs usually don't add too much overhead unless you're trying to perform really complex queries. As long as the generated SQL statement is the same, the in-process overhead is neglible (the database and network are more significant than creating and translating some objects in memory)